# EditText's padding issue

Tags: android, alignment, android-edittext

In xml layout, I already have set gravity = center. However, It seems it's still top alignment. So I'm thinking there's something else that I'm missing like padding.

Is there anybody that once had similar experience?

See the illustration here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p70zdxkbpcdlem7/make%20edittxt.png

Below is my layout file:

```
 <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/subheading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="60"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:tag="1001"
                        android:gravity="center|top"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext_editable"
                        android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: Could you attach the xml code as well ?

Comment: your illustration just confused me. Can you show your layout xml ?

Comment: can u place your xml code?

Comment: do you want to center horizontally or vertically?

Comment: show layout XML and image of edittext that causing problem??

Comment: if you are using LinearLayout then just make android:layout_gravity="center" and if you are set text of edittext then set gravity="center"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` for the parent view.

it should solve your problem

Comment: it just doesn't work like that without having proper settings to layout_height and etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:gravity = center
```

`EditText` places *text inside it* at center.

and

```
android:layout_gravity = center
```

`EditText`'s *parent places it* at center.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your xml code here? Try to change the width and height properties of EditText and layout in which it is from "wrap_content" to "match_parent" and vice versa, and look for behavior.

Thank you, for post your code! Try to remove "top" in line android:gravity="center|top"